# Does Google Cloud Storage work for the app I coded using PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, pysimplegui

Im developing a financial app using PySimpleGUI.

This is a desktop app, and will be sold publicly on my web page. I need a place to store my future clients data.

Does Google Cloud Storage work for a Desktop App, and is it safe? ( There will be sensitive financial data stored ). Also, multiple people will be editing the files simultaneously, will this cause the Google Cloud Storage to break?

Will you recommend me using something else for storing my data?

Thanks

I have tried connecting to SQL Server, but it only works for computers that are on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of components is way out of sync. My suggestion would be to first see what the actual requirements are. One small example would be how many people at a time will access the application, what data access controls will be present, how will you implement them? Can you use features of GCP or will you be developing your own? In any of the scenarios, are you involving data masking? What would be the design to expand the application in long run, etc. etc. Also a small disclaimer, the above queries have barely scratched the surface of the complexities involved in designing such data systems.

Once done, go through the list of tools available in GCP. See, what fits and how an efficient chain can be established.

Also, connecting to GCP via python works anywhere depending on how you setup the environment.